# Three numbers a, b and c are chosen at random, with replacement, from the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 99.

Tags: probability

> Three numbers a, b and c are chosen at random, with replacement, from the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 99.

> The probability that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ is divisible by 3 is-

I can't really find a starting point to approach this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $a^3 \equiv a \pmod 3$ by Fermat's Little Theorem or factorization. $3abc$ is always divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun question, lets break it down a little. Firstly I will introduce some modular arithmetic notation:

$x$ mod $y$ means the reminder when $x$ is divided by $y$.

For example: $25$ mod $7$ = $4$ as $25 = 3 \cdot 7 + \textbf{4} $
Another example: $19$ mod $3$ = $1$ as $19 = 6 \cdot 3 + \textbf{1} $

$\textbf{Property of Mods:}$

$x_1 + x_2 $ mod $y = x_1$ mod $y$ + $x_2$ mod $y$

Now onto mod $3$. There are $3$ seperate cases. Firstly $x$ mod $3$ can be $0 , 1 $ or $2$

$\textbf{Case 0} $

If $x$ mod $3 = 0$ then $x$ is a multiple of $3$ and can be written as $3k$ for some number $k$. And hence $x^3 = (3k)^3 = 27k^3 = 3y$. Where $y = 9k^3$. This is also a multiple of $3$ as $x^3 = 3y$

I.e if $x$ mod $3 = 0$ then $x^3$ mod $3 = 0$

$\textbf{Case 1} $

If $x$ mod $3 = 1$ then $x = 3k +1 $ for some integer k and hence $x^3 = (3k+1)^3 = 27k^3 + 27k^2 + 9k + 1  = 3(9k^3 +9k^2 + 3k) + 1$ and again if we let $y = 9k^3 +9k^2 + 3k$ then $x^3 = 3y + 1 $ and from our property of mods we have $x^3$ mod $3$ = $3y +1$ mod $3$ = $3y$ mod $3 + 1 $ mod $3$ = $ 0 + 1$ = 1. So to summarise: If $x$ mod $3 = 1$ then $x^3$ mod $3$ = $1$

$\textbf{Case 2} $

If $x$ mod $3 = 2$ then $x = 3k +2 $ for some integer k and hence $x^3 = (3k+2)^3 = 27k^3 + 54k^2 + 36k + 8  = 27k^3 + 54k^2 + 36k + 6 + 2 =  3(9k^3 + 18k^2 + 12k + 2) + 2$ and again if we let $y = 9k^3 + 18k^2 + 12k + 2$ then $x^3 = 3y + 2 $ and from our property of mods we have $x^3$ mod $3$ = $3y +2$ mod $3$ = $3y$ mod $3 + 2 $ mod $3$ = $ 0 + 2$ = 2. So to summarise: If $x$ mod $3 = 2$ then $x^3$ mod $3$ = $2$

Now this shows that $x$ mod $3$ = $x^3$ mod $3$ for all different choices of x.

Now onto your problem:

We want to find out what needs to happen for $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ to be divisible by 3. This is the same as $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ mod $3 = 0. $ Using our property of mods we have: $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ mod $3$ =

$a^3$ mod $3$ + $b^3$ mod $3$ + $c^3$ mod $3$ - $3abc$ mod $3$.

Firstly as $3abc$ is a multiple of 3 we have $3abc$ mod $3$ = 0 so:

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ mod $3$  = $a^3$ mod $3$ + $b^3$ mod $3$ + $c^3$ mod $3$ But we know that $x^3$ mod $3$ =  $x$ mod $3$ so :

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ mod $3$ =  $a$ mod $3$ + $b$ mod $3$ + $c$ mod $3$ = $a + b + c $ mod $3$

Hence in order for $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ to be divisible by 3 all we need is $a + b + c $  to be divisible by 3

If $a,b,c$ are all picked randomly from $1-99$ then a third of the numbers are exactly divisible by $3: 3,9,12,...,96,99.$ Another third are divisible with remainder 1: $1,4,7,...,94,97$ and the final third are divisible with reminder 2: $2,5,8,...,95,98$ and thus Probability( $a$ or $b$ or $c$ mod $3$ =$ 0 )$  = $\frac{1}{3} $and the Probability( $a$ or $b$ or $c$ mod $3$ =$ 1 )$  = $\frac{1}{3} $ and the Probability( $a$ or $b$ or $c$ mod $3$ =$ 2 )$  = $\frac{1}{3}.$

As $a + b + c$ mod $3$ = $a + b $ mod $3$ + $c$ mod $3$ and so in order to have $a + b + c$ mod $3$ = $0$ we can first pick $a$ and $b$ and not really care about what they are because there will always be one and exactly 1 value for $c$ mod $3$ that will ensure this value is $0$

i.e if  $a + b $ mod $3$ = $1$ then we just need a $c$ such that $c$ mod $3$ = $2$

or if $a + b $ mod $3$ = $0 $ then we just need a $c$ such that $c$ mod $3$ = $0 $

or if $a + b $ mod $3$ = $2 $ then we just need a $c$ such that $c$ mod $3$ = $1$

The probability of either of this required cases for $c$ is $\frac{1}{3} $

And thus the probability that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ is divisible by $3 = \frac{1}{3}$

Oskar :)